# Access validation rule violation update query across multiple tables

Tags: ms-access

I would like to create an update query to update a yes/no field in one table (called 'pmh' for past medical history) based on the numeric value of a field in another table (called 'bloods'). I am trying to populate a yes/no field for kidney disease based on a blood test result.

If I do this when both fields are in one table, it works. If I try and do it across two tables, I get a 'Validation rule violation' error message. Apart from being in one or two tables, the fields are exactly the same. There are no validation rules or zerolength criteria in either the tables or fields.

I wonder whether this is something to do with the join type in Relationships. I have set the join type to 2 ('Include ALL records from 'bloods' and only those records from 'pmh' where the joined fields are equal') - because I want to be able to see all patients with a value in the 'bloods' table.

The relationship between the tables is one-to-one - each patient has only one set of blood tests - the reason for not using one table is that the number of fields would be greater than 255.

I hope this makes sense - I have tried to make it as succinct as I can. Thanks everyone for your help, and let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like data structure is not normalized. Saving calculated data is usually a bad idea. The Y/N value can be calculated when needed.

Join type set in relationships builder should not prevent update. Should provide attempted query for analysis. Is it like:

`UPDATE pmh INNER JOIN bloods ON pmh.ID = bloods.ID SET pmh.fieldname = IIf([bloods.fieldname]="something", True, False);`

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply - here is the attempted query that I am having trouble with: `UPDATE bloods LEFT JOIN PMH ON bloods.OxAMI_ID = pmh.ID SET pmh.CKD = No
WHERE (((Patients.Creatinine)<200));`

Comment: I've just tested with your code - it works if I use an inner join, but not with the code I've pasted above. Do you know whether I can make it work with a left join?

Comment: It works for me but why is it necessary to use LEFT for an UPDATE? Have you considered my advisory that the UPDATE isn't even needed at all? Can calculate the Y/N value when needed.

Comment: Thanks - you're right. Probably better to calculate this field when needed.